# VideoCapture while video is being recorded

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently trying to read frames of a video as it is being written to.

First of all, is this even possible?
I tried the code shown below. Two output examples are shown, one where I try to read live, one where I read afterwards. The frame counter is much lower on the first case, so certainly this doesn't work as it is now, but I am out of ideas on what else to try.

If anyone could help either by confirming whether this is possible or not, or with ideas on how to achieve this, that'd be awesome.

```py
import cv2
import time

videoPath = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Video.ts'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)

totalCount = 0
frameCount = 0
idleTimer = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if ret is False this is the current end of the video
    if (ret is False):
        idleTimer += 10

        # Show how many frames were read since last idle time, and total frames read
        totalCount += frameCount
        print ('Read ' + str(frameCount) + ' frames. Total frames: ' + str(totalCount))

        # Reset current frame count
        frameCount = 0

        # Wait 10 seconds (for the video file to grow)
        time.sleep(10)

    else:
        idleTimer = 0
        frameCount += 1

    # If idle 3x in a row, assume video is no longer being written to
    if (idleTimer >= 30):
        cap.release()
```

Running this code on a video during recording gives:

```
Read 169 frames. Total frames: 169
Read 257 frames. Total frames: 426
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 426
Read 251 frames. Total frames: 677
Read 29 frames. Total frames: 706
Read 2 frames. Total frames: 708
Read 73 frames. Total frames: 781
Read 1 frames. Total frames: 782
Read 57 frames. Total frames: 839
Read 1 frames. Total frames: 840
Read 55 frames. Total frames: 895
Read 1 frames. Total frames: 896
Read 38 frames. Total frames: 934
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 934
Read 251 frames. Total frames: 1185
Read 8 frames. Total frames: 1193
Read 152 frames. Total frames: 1345
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 1345
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 1345
```

But running after recording is finished:

```
Read 4354 frames. Total frames: 4354
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 4354
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 4354
```

Many thanks.

**Edit:** I did some extra testing on this - my code now records the processed frames into a new video, so I can compare what's been processed and what hasn't.

```py
if (cap.isOpened()):
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Video_copy.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), fps, (width, height))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if ret is False this is the current end of the video
    if (ret is False):
        idleTimer += 10

        # Show how many frames were read since last idle time, and total frames read
        totalCount += frameCount
        print ('Read ' + str(frameCount) + ' frames. Total frames: ' + str(totalCount) + '. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: ' + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))
        print ('Idling...')

        # Reset current frame count
        frameCount = 0
        time.sleep(10)

    else:
        #Write this frame to new video
        out.write(frame)
        idleTimer = 0
        frameCount += 1

    # If idle 3x in a row, assume video is no longer being written to
    if (idleTimer >= 30):
        cap.release()
        out.release()
        print ('Video has been released.')
```

If I run this on a video I'm just recording, the output will look like this:

```py
Read 1197 frames. Total frames: 1197. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 115 frames. Total frames: 1312. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 169 frames. Total frames: 1481. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 291 frames. Total frames: 1772. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 138 frames. Total frames: 1910. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 142 frames. Total frames: 2052. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 152 frames. Total frames: 2204. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 186 frames. Total frames: 2390. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 358 frames. Total frames: 2748. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 124 frames. Total frames: 2872. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 329 frames. Total frames: 3201. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 3201. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 3201. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 911.0
Video has been released.
```

There is an interesting behaviour here: `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` does not change its value throughout execution, even though the video is obviously growing in size. Also, from the first iteration, it returns a value that's lower than the number of processed frames.

Running the same code after recording is complete, the numbers now all match.

```py
Read 4349 frames. Total frames: 4349. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 4349.0
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 4349. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 4349.0
Read 0 frames. Total frames: 4349. CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT: 4349.0
Video has been released.
```

Also, playing the `Video_copy` that I am recording, I can confirm I am getting new frames after each 10s wait, but there are holes in it (as expected, since my live execution processed 3201 and the post execution processed 4349 frames).

Comment: This may be an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). How do you record the video and what you want to use it for?

Comment: I am recording a mirrored iphone screen using [this app](https://www.apowersoft.com/phone-mirror). I am recording in .ts format because it allows to play it as it's being written (as far as I'm aware). Regarding usage, I want to be able to process the frames as/soon after they are written to the file.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe check what happens with the total frame count: `length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print( length )` First check only when `ret is false`

Comment: I've tried that - added more information to the question. I think that revealed quite an interesting property of `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` (and potentially of other VideoCapture properties), in that they seem to be set when the object is created, instead of being dynamic (this was not obvious to me before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my specific problem, which is shown below.

The key is to reload the `VideoCapture` object. I am working with videos up to 3 minutes long (for now), and successive calls of `cv2.VideoCapture()` did not seem to take more and more time - I assume it only creates a reference to the video, so it's rather lightweight.

```py
if (cap.isOpened()):
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Video_copy.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), fps, (width, height))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # If ret is False this is the current end of the video
    if (ret is False):
        cap.release()
        out.release()
        print ('Video has been released.')

    # If not, let's record this new frame
    else:
        #Write this frame to new video
        out.write(frame)
        frameCount += 1

    # If I'm 3 frames away from the end, try to reload the video
    # 3 is an arbitrary number (I want it to try to get more frames at least 3 times
    # before deciding that the video is indeed over and releasing
    # If the video grew in size in the last 10 seconds, this will get the new frames
    # For some reason this wouldn't work if I let it go all the way to the end

    if (frameCount > (cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) - 3)):
        time.sleep(10)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        # Jump to the frame I just processed, to avoid re-reading the whole video
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameCount - 1)
```

Hope this may be helpful to someone.